# Network media player has disappeared from Win10's File Explorer's "Computer" category, but is still in the "Media Devices" category

Tags: windows, media-player

I apologize if the following is not appropriate for the tag I have used and I would appreciate a redirect to the correct place.  If stackoverflow is simply the wrong place for this altogether, I'll be glad to delete it :-)

I have three Intel-based PCs, all of which are running the latest version of Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.  I also have a WDTV media player with a USB drive connected to it.  All three PCs as well as the WDTV are connected to a common LAN via Ethernet.  There are no settings in the WDTV that specify which network devices are allowed to use it but instead, any network device that has its password should be able to access it and transfer files to/from its USB drive.

When I select "Network" in the left frame of Windows File Explorer, the WDTV device is listed in both the "Computer" and "Media Devices" categories in the right frame on the PC with the newest Win10 installation, but only in the "Media Devices" category on the other two PCs.  On the PC where it is listed in both categories I can access the WDTV's USB drive and transfer files to/from it, but on the other two PCs the USB drive is not even visible.  When Win10 was originally installed on the other two PCs the WDTV device was visible in both categories on them too and I could transfer to/from its USB drive, but something has obviously changed through all the various application installations and whatnot that have occurred since then.

I am far from a Windows or a network expert and my question is specifically how to debug this to find out the cause and correct it.  I realize I can do a complete reinstallation of everything but that is something I'd prefer to avoid if possible and without knowing the actual cause, it's likely the problem will eventually return anyway.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the WDTV device uses the 'SMB 1.0/CIFS' network protocol, which was only enabled on my newest PC installation.  After enabling it on my two other PCs the WDTV device once again became accessible by them too.  There is also an "automatic removal" setting for 'SMB 1.0/CIFS'.  My GUESS is that it was likely initially set on both of the other PCs and caused the protocol to be removed during a Windows update :-(